# Is it possible to skip code generation for included thrift files in Scrooge?

Tags: sbt, thrift, scrooge

The Scrooge SBT plugin has the option to include Thrift IDL files from library dependencies (jar files). Often these jar files already contain the generated sources. If I include a Thrift IDL, I don't want to generate these sources again. Otherwise they will be duplicated.

**shared.thift**

```
namespace java me.shared

struct Foo {
  1: string id
}
```

**shared.jar**

```
me
  shared
    Foo.scala
shared.thrift
```

So when my project depends on shared.jar and I include shared.thrift in another Thrift IDL file, I don't want Scrooge to generate Foo.scala again. What's the most straight-forward way to archive this?

Answer (score 1):

It was actually straight-forward.

```
scroogeThriftSources in Compile ~= { sources: Seq[File] =>
  sources filter { case file =>
    !file.getName.contains("shared.thrift")
  }
}
```